I get a premature EOF error from the w3c html validator and my Safari browser, yet the document is fine
The w3c validator.nu is giving me this bizarre error when I try to validate the document:
https:// ssh - test . me / booking 

(remove all spaces before you copy-paste)
If you hit the ‘source’ option it shows the document truncated at </bo or </bod in the closing </body> tag. This however is not the case.
There is something deeper going on here though, as the document is xhtml, so the browser - I use iPadOS Safari - immediately shows any errors. And so luckily it shows the exact same error on line 46 iirc, error message "> expected" and again in the middle of the </body> tag.
Can anyone help me understand this? I tried a copy-paste from another xhtml document just to rule out garve in my source code, but no change.

You can check the above document by going to the URL quoted. And the w3c validator can be found by Googling "validator.nu", or going direct to https://validator.nu/?showsource=yes&doc=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ssh-test.me%2Fbooking

Whatever I try, to access your booking page, I always get the same result: The page ends prematurely with </bo. This calls into question your statement: "This however is not the case.". What makes you say that?

I realise now what is going on. On my own machine the document is fine. But the copy on the webserver is truncated according to a hexdump, so I’m seeing what you’re seeing. It took me a while to realise that the two are not the same. Doh.

Yeah, I expected it would be something like that.

I realise now what is going on. On my own machine the document is fine. But the copy on the webserver is truncated according to a hexdump. It took me a while to realise that the two are not the same. Doh. So now to work out how the upload is corrupting this document.

What happens if you simply reupload the file?
